# Is it possible to bypass HTML character reference encoding to inject SQL in this context?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I was poking around with the "reset password" page of a website (security testing and bug hunting is allowed on it.)

When you put in your email address, it uses HTML character reference encoding to encode your address. For example:

Email: `example@example.com` >> `example&#x40;example.com`

Is it possible to inject SQL commands even through it's been encoded like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the hex encoding happening? server-side or client-side?

Comment: Server Side. why?

Comment: If it was client side there would still be an attack vector. Obvious I guess, but worth asking.

Comment: @Mico, how can you tell that replacement is happening at the serverside? Do you have access to the server?

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection works by skipping out from the "value" part of SQL syntax into the "command" part.

String values (as in your example) are surrounded by quotes - to break out you would need to include a similar quote in your value (like `' WHERE 1; DROP TABLE ...` or whatever the actual syntax would be).  HTML encoding doesn't allow quotes, so that won't work.

I did wonder a bit about unquoted fields - e.g. if it's expecting a number (from a dropdown) but you give it a command (like `5 WHERE 1; DROP TABLE ...` or whatever).  However, I'm not aware of any single-word SQL statements - i.e. you can't do anything without something to separate the tokens (e.g. a space  or punctuation `(` etc.).  So even if you were looking at an unquoted field like a number then you could screw up the statement and produce an error, but not actually execute anything.

Comment: Input values are not only used as literals. They may also be used as identifiers, syntax components like keywords, operators, etc.

Comment: The question was about value-escaping.  If you're using user-submitted input as SQL keywords, then you've gone way past "insufficient escaping" into "wtf, are you getting paid per vulnerability?" ;)